# Get the top most parent directory in Python

Tags: python, directory, parent

> > > path
> > >       'h:\OmWPDump_Tue_Oct_07_21_08_13_2014\windows\SystemsManagementx64\SysMgmtx64.msi'
> > >       os.path.dirname(path)
> > >       'h:\OmWPDump_Tue_Oct_07_21_08_13_2014\windows\SystemsManagementx64'

I need the code for so that it outputs the top most parent directory. :
'h:\OmWPDump_Tue_Oct_07_21_08_13_2014;

Basically I would need this location so that I remove the complete directory .

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method without requiring additional modules is to `split()` the path:

```
>>> path = r'h:\OmWPDump_Tue_Oct_07_21_08_13_2014\windows\SystemsManagementx64\SysMgmtx64.msi'
>>> topdir = path.split('\\')[1]
>>> topdir
'OmWPDump_Tue_Oct_07_21_08_13_2014'
```

If you're potentially dealing with UNC paths, then you may need check first and determine which element to use (`split()` on a UNC path will return a couple of empty elements, then hostname, then your top-level folder).

Edit:
Add to that your drive from the path:

```
>>> deldir = os.path.join(os.path.splitdrive(path), topdir)
>>> deldir
'h:\\OmWPDump_Tue_Oct_07_21_08_13_2014'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re
path = 'h:\OmWPDump_Tue_Oct_07_21_08_13_2014\windows\SystemsManagementx64\SysMgmtx64.msi'
match = re.findall(r'.:\\.+\\', path)
answer = match[0][:-1]
```